# Passing an Entity to a FormType so its methods can be run in buildForm() in Symfony2

Tags: php, xml, symfony, symfony-forms

Started working with the Symfony framework and so far all has went well, but the following has me stumped.

I have need to pull previously persisted data to prepopulate some fields on another stage of a multi page form.

I had hoped to just pass in the object in order to use its methods but I can't seem to get it to work.

For example:

foo.php

```
...

$form = $this->formFactory->create('foo_type', $article);

...
```

fooType.php

```
...

protected $article;

    public function __construct(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
    }

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add(
                'fooTitle',
                'text',
                array('data' => $this->article->getTitle())
            );
    }

...
```

forms.xml

```
    <service id="footType" class="\Path\To\File\fooType">
        <argument type="service" id="article" />
        <tag name="form.type" alias="foo_type" />
    </service>
```

I feel like I am missing out a crucial step somewhere but i'm struggling to understand how to relate the xml with the type class being used to build the form.

Comment: As you discovered, using a constructor is not going to work.  Especially when you upgrade to S3.  Form events can give you access to the data object: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormBuilder` should NOT manipulate entity data, because as its name stands for, its role is to build the different fields of a `Form`.

About populating fields, it is actually pretty simple: if you set an attribute on your entity, when you bind your entity to your `Form`, the related field (i.e. the field with the same name as your attribute) will have its data changed adequately.

Example :

**FooType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', 'text');
}
```

**Foo.php**

```
$article->setTitle('HELLO');
$this->formFactory->create('foo_type', $article);
```

Then, your `FormView` will directly have its `title` field filled with `"HELLO"`.